# How to fix "Support-v13:19.1.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-gradle-plugin

I just launched a project in Android Studio 0.8.1 for the first time since upgrading from 0.6.2.

The error thrown is "Error:Module version com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself".

Does anyone have an idea why this is? I have installed some of the new API20 stuff to play with Android L, but the buildTools for this project are still set to 19.1.0.

Here's the dependencies section of my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.+'
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.0'
   compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
   compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:0.7.+'
   compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.+'
}
```

SDK/Buildtools settings are as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

Can anyone explain this or point me towards a fix? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like the `support-v13:19.1.0` might have incorrect metadata. Try switching to

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'` and see if your problem persists?

Comment: I started getting the error after adding `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus` dependency, and this worked for me too.

Comment: what bothers me is this works but i have no idea why. i feel like i arbitrarily have to change around my dependencies without rhyme or reason.