# Android build.gradle error v13:19.1.0

Tags: android, build.gradle

Gradle build finishes correctly with the **build.gradle** file below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.etu.goglove"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0'

}
```

But I'm trying to implement also **MapsActivity.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_fragment);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Then I get errors about the import I make: **cannot resolve symbol 'android'**
I have also Google Play Services installed. Then in the build.gradle file I add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
```

Then I get this error:

```
Warning:Module 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
```

What do I wrong? This solution not helps ..[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610525/how-to-fix-support-v1319-1-0-depends-on-libraries-but-is-not-a-library-itself)

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing gradle build this may solve problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem updating your `compileSdkVersion`, you may try changing it to something newer like `23.0.2` and the same version for your libraries too (`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.2'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.2'`).

If you want to stick with `19` for any reason, you may try changing your `buildToolsVersion` to `19.1.0`.

At last, try cleaning the project and try building again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
```

And replace this

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.1.0'
```

with

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

why you are set target version 18 this is old one

change to 25 or 24